# Yarn packages won't update for dependency issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yarnpkg

On a development server, for an application barely deployed, rails commands won't execute because of lack of integrity file.

```
error Couldn't find an integrity file
error Found 1 errors.


========================================
  Your Yarn packages are out of date!
  Please run `yarn install --check-files` to update.
========================================
```

Both

```
yarn install --check-files
yarn install
```

lead to the same error

```
compression-webpack-plugin@4.0.1: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">= 10.13.0". Got "8.17.0"
Found incompatible module
 Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

The 'visit' prompt is unfortunately of no use, as it does not deal with the node engine.

Being barely deployed, there is no node-modules directory yet, which is expected.  However on development machine there is the directory and no issues whatseoever in precompiling assets.
Server context:

```
node -v
> v8.17.0
```

How can this situation be unblocked?

Comment: what OS are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to update the node to a version higher than the one mentioned `>= 10.13.0` then re-install yarn and re-run the check:

if you're on Mac OS:

```sh
brew install node@14 && brew link --force node@14
brew install yarn
```

[if you're on Linux:](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-20-04)

```sh
cd ~
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x -o nodesource_setup.sh
sudo bash nodesource_setup.sh
sudo apt install nodejs
```

then check if you have a compatible version

````sh
node -v
=> v14.2.0
``

if so re-run any of your commands:

```bash
yarn install --check-files
yarn install
````

Comment: Rails handle versions of gems but not of the node even if you had yarn configured it will still fail if your node library is outdated because it's an external dependency  - probably in the target os it has a missing dependency I normally keep an eye on logs upon failure and see what is missing, Good luck!